# signal is processed by children but not by parent process?

Tags: python, signals

I spawn several `multiprocessing.Process`es to share the workload onto different procs.
Now i want to be able to close the whole program by pressing Ctrl-C, but the signal is only send to the childs and not to the parent process.

my program looks like this:

```
import sys
import multiprocessing
import signal

# ignoring handler, signal.SIG_IGN is not working on windows
def sighandler(signal, frame):
    pass    

# worker thread definiton
def worker():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sighandler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sighandler)

    # do stuff here...

def main():
    num_procs = 4
    procs = []
    print("Starting up %d processes:" %num_procs)
    for i in range(num_procs):
        print("\tstarting worker %d..." %(i+1))
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
        procs.append(p)
        p.start()

    print("All processes started...")
    try:
        for p in procs:
            p.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        print "STOPPING"

        for p in procs:
            p.terminate()

        sys.exit(0)
```

but only the sighandler is called 4 times if i press ctrl-c. when i register signals in the parent process, the handler is not called nor is the KeyboardInterrupt exception working.
can i stop the child process from the inside? a `sys.exit(0)` inside the handler is not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `os._exit(n)`?

From the docs:

> Exit the process with status n, without calling cleanup handlers, flushing stdio buffers, etc.
>
> Availability: Unix, Windows.
>
> Note The standard way to exit is sys.exit(n). _exit() should normally only be used in the child process after a fork().

http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os._exit

Comment: well, interestingly enough, if i do this in the signal handler, even the `KeyboardInterrupt` is processed perfectly...